# Rotating an array:Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV)

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

> Given an array of `N` size. The task is to rotate array by `d`
>   elements where `d` is less than or equal to `N`.
>
> Constraints: 1 ≤ T ≤ 200 1 ≤ N ≤ 200 1 ≤ A[i] ≤ 1000
>
> Example input:
>
> ```
> 1
> 5
> 1 2 3 4 5
> 2
> ```
>
> Output
>
> ```
> 3 4 5 1 2
> ```

The program I wrote seems legit but when I tried to run it is giving me segment fault. I even ran the above example I'm getting the correct output.
The source is [GeeksforGeeks: Rotating and Array](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/reversal-algorithm/0/?track=sp-arrays-and-searching&batchId=152).

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int test_case, numb, from, arr[200];

  cin >> test_case;
  while (test_case--) {
    cin >> numb;

    for (int i = 0; i < numb; i++) {
      cin >> arr[i];
    }

    cin >> from;
    for (int i = from; i < numb; i++) {
      cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < from; j++) {
      cout << arr[j] << " ";
    }

    cout << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

What are the changes which my code needs? What can I do to avoid such errors in the future?[click_to_see_segment_fault](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/pKOAv6cA4e)

Comment: You have to make sure numb is less than 200, because arr only has 200 spaces. So that is one possible issue where you can seg fault. Same as the 3rd loop ensure from is not > 200

Comment: segmentation fault at compile time? and you ran the program and got the correct output? Your statements are contradictory

Comment: For what all inputs do you get the segmentation fault

Comment: @Inian I edited it to run time. Happy?Solution?

Comment: Show us the exact input you fed when you saw the Seg fault. The one you shown in the question does not throw one

Comment: @OmidCompSCI But it should not matter because my program is running from 0 to number. Program is not accessing any index where there could be garbage value.

Comment: You should check all input values as it is described in the home task.

Comment: @Inian The site in which I'm practicing is not giving me input list but I gave the link, try running the code it will give Segment Fault.

Comment: It only gives a seg fault if you don't provide any input to the compiler. So the variable `test_case` is still uninitialized and you use it in if statement which invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @eras'q: It seems that you  need to pass the input in the text box that says 'Input goes here'. When I pasted the input to there, it worked just fine. It is throwing the error when the box is empty

Comment: @S.M. I don't get it. Input values in the home task? can you please elaborate what you mean?

Comment: @Inian But In the previous link where the question is given I'm trying to submit my solution and nothing is happening.

Comment: @0x499602D2 But In the previous link where the question is given I'm trying to submit my solution and nothing is happening.

Comment: So long as the input is within the ranges specified, your code will output the array as it would be rotated. However, if you don't validate your user input, you won't know. Many of these "challenge" questions intentionally include data that is outside the ranges specified to see if your code handles the error correctly. You can add validation to each input in the time it takes to read this comment. Also, `#include <iostream>` instead of `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`. Both will work, the latter is discouraged.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin But in the question, they didn't state that what my program should output when data is outside the given range.

Comment: Fair enough -- given that the answers indicate your code works, (and I can confirm what you have will work for the input specified), it is completely unclear where you are getting your error. You can compile your code and run it with `printf "1\n5\n1 2 3 4 5\n2\n" | ./yourexe` and see that the output is correct. You remain in bounds for all cases and if `d == N`, your first output loop is skipped and the second simply outputs the array unchanged (as it should).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Can you check joker007 answer. He said the site is accepting my code and is displaying **correct answer** but when I'm clicking on submitting nothing happens.

Comment: It sounds like you have javascript disabled in your browser making parts of the page inactive or some other issue such as that. Double check that on your end because I have no doubt that if submitted the results will be as @joker007 describes.

Comment: @eras'q Tip: Most people here aren't familiar with the aspects of competitive programming such as assuming the input is valid and secret test cases.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Cleared the cache and enabled javascript still unable to submit anything else can be done?

Comment: I hate to ask, but are you using internet explorer? Some pages simply don't work with it. (MS has been slowly trying to kill it off, even in W10). If you are using FF or chrome, I don't know what to tell you. At this point, this isn't a code problem, it is a browser/site problem. It may be best to migrate this question to the stack-exchange site [**Super User**](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I'm using chrome. I'll migrate the question. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It turned out there was some problem with the email I was using I still don't know what. Once I logged in from another google account everything was working fine.

Comment: Glad you got it working. "To err is human, but to really fowl things up requires a computer...."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Just submitted your exact code on [Rotating an Array | Geek for Geeks](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/reversal-algorithm/0/?track=sp-arrays-and-searching&batchId=152) (site given in the question) . It works perfectly , and no run time error was encountered .

Comment: You were able to submit the solution (as per the question's link )or you made it run as per second link(click_here_for_input)?

Comment: question's link, and i pasted your code in their IDE while submitting.

Comment: I don't get it. The IDE is to check wheater the code is correct or not.right(second link)? And where the question is given(first link) there are three buttons **Expected Output  Compile&test  Submit** when I'm clicking the submit button nothing is happening. And when clicking the compile&test it is stuck on evaluating...

Comment: IDE is in both 1st and 2nd link . And yeah there are 3 buttons as you said , and on "submitting" , it is showing correct answer . And what do you mean by nothing is happening ?

Comment: When I'm clicking on submit button nothing is happening. The page remains the same without a tad bit of change. Where is the **correct answer** part is displaying?

Comment: just below the IDE .

Comment: @eras'q you can check the image that i just added in the answer

Comment: Nothing is happening on my page. Is there anything You can recommend?

Comment: Try clearing browser's cache and make sure that java script isn't disabled .

Comment: Enabled Javascript and clearing cache is taking forever. Its been 10min.

Comment: Did both still unable to submit.

Comment: Well , then it's an altogether different issue unrelated from what was asked in the question, please start another thread for this . And please up vote this answer if you found it helpful .

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to upvote it but I marked it as correct.

Comment: It turned out there was some problem with the email I was using I still don't know what. Once I logged in from another google account everything was working fine.

Comment: @eras'q this is indeed surprising , I have never heard about anything like this . Anyways , i am glad you solved it . How did you come to realize there could be problem with the email ?

Comment: I did not, I thought of doing everything I could. I tried changing browser it didn't work. The only option was to login in from another account.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int test_case, numb, from, arr[200];
    cout<< "Enter the numbe of test cases"<<endl;
    cin >> test_case;
    if(test_case > 200)
    {
            cout<<"Number of test cases above limit";
            return 0;
    }
    while (test_case--) {
            cout<<"START TEST CASE"<<test_case<<endl;
            cout<<"Enter the number of elements in the array"<<endl;
            cin >> numb;
            if(numb > 200)
            {
                    cout<<"Array size more than expected skipping testcase"<<endl;
                    continue;
            }
            cout<<"Enter the elements of array"<<endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < numb; i++) {
                    cin >> arr[i];
            }
            cout<<"Enter the number of rotations"<<endl;
            cin >> from;
            if(from > numb || from < 0)
            {
                    cout <<"rotation index out of range skipping testcase"<<endl;
                    continue;
            }
            for (int i = from; i < numb; i++) {
                    cout << arr[i] << " ";
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < from; j++) {
                    cout << arr[j] << " ";
            }

            cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Extending @Charlie's answer,
The program checks for numbs ranges and from's range.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following input and will see weird results. The problem is when the `from` is greater than the number of elements itself. Basically you need to do a check to see whether the `from` itself is more than the number of elements or not `numb`.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int test_case, numb, from, arr[200];
  cout<<"\nEnter number of test cases:";
  cin >> test_case;
  cout<<"Test cases = "<<test_case<<endl;
  while (test_case--) {
    cout<<"Enter count of elements:";
    cin >> numb;
  cout<<"Count= "<<numb<<endl;

cout<<"Enter the elements:";
    for (int i = 0; i < numb; i++) {
      cin >> arr[i];
    }
cout<<"Entered elements are :";
    for (int i = 0; i < numb; i++) {
      cout << arr[i]<<" ";
    }

cout<<"\nHow many times to rotated? :";
    cin >> from;
cout<<"\nRotate it "<<from<<" times:\n";
    for (int i = from; i < numb; i++) {
      cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < from; j++) {
      cout << arr[j] << " ";
    }

    cout << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Lets provide the input as follows:

```
Enter number of test cases:1
Test cases = 1
Enter count of elements:1
Count= 1
Enter the elements:2
Entered elements are :2
How many times to rotated? :2

Rotate it 2 times:
2 32666
```

You see the mistake? The location where 32666 is a problem here. It could crash too in your case.

Comment: The task is to rotate array by d elements where d is less than or equal to N.
As in your case 'd' cannot be greater than 1 . Thus , situation like this won't arise in this problem .

Comment: Sure. I am just showing that a faulty input could lead to this situation and to avoid crashes you need to put checks. In the program there is no check to make sure that  `d is less than or equal to N`. Apart from that there seems to be nothing wrong to lead to a crash. Im sure OP must have provided wrong input leading to a crash

Comment: Yeah , but in practice questions, input cannot be outside of the given constraints.

Comment: As mentioned by OP, the input was provided by her and not by the website itself. If the website had provided the input, there would have been rare chance that the input is faulty. But since OP entered the input himself/herself, chances are that the input was faulty as i mentioned in my answer because apart from that there is no other way to lead to a crash

Comment: Where did OP mention that input was given by her ?

Comment: In the comments of the question